# Information explaining the relationship between Debian and Ubuntu

Tags: debian, community, upstream

Please post articles or blog posts that detail the relationship between Debian and Ubuntu (negative/positive) that you find insightful/useful/excellent... and please don't limit this to just the OS, but also the rest of their respective eco-systems.

Comment: Perhaps you'd have more luck if you asked for people to describe the relationship themselves (with sources, naturally) rather than just links to discussions. Either way, this sounds pretty open-ended and should be a community wiki (there's a checkbox on the edit page).

Comment: You're here to ask questions that benefit to everyone and not to demand thing that benefit only for you. Please rewrite your question if you don't want it to be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here is a talk](http://ubuntudevelopers.blip.tv/file/3982047/) I gave at Debconf 10 on the relationship between our two projects. I'm afraid the audio quality isn't so hot but I go over some of the things we're working on.

- Our Debian [workspace](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debian) on the wiki. This has the basic information.
- The Debian derivatives front-desk has [pointers to places](http://wiki.debian.org/DerivativesFrontDesk) where people who are interested in working with Debian can collaborate.
- The Ultimate Debian Database has [some measurements](http://udd.debian.org/cgi-bin/ubuntu_usertag.cgi) of Ubuntu contributions, the video explains how to read these.
- Here's an already [out of date list](http://castrojo.tumblr.com/post/977240439/developers-with-feet-in-debian-and-ubuntu) I compiled of people who are both Ubuntu developers and Debian developers.

Answer (score 2):

An [interview with Colin Watson](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/11/25/people-behind-debian-colin-watson/) is a gem. See the 2nd half to see the Ubuntu-specific parts.